# ARKit – How to know if 3d object is in the center of a screen?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, frustum

I place 3d object in the world space. After that I try to move camera randomly. Then right now I need to know after I knew object has became inside frustum by `isNode` method, if the object is in center, top or bottom of camera view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with another way:

```
 let results = self.sceneView.hitTest(screenCenter!, options: [SCNHitTestOption.rootNode: parentnode])
```

where `parentnode` is the parent of target node, because I have multiple nodes.

Comment: In this scenario, I got exactly what I need, but the problem: the result returned only when camera above the center of object. I need each point of node inside the bouding box, why????????

Comment: I'm glad you found your scenario. But Hit-testing and Ray-casting are more CPU intensive, especially `trackedRaycast()` method.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

To achieve this you need to use a trick. Create new SCNCamera, make it a child of `pointOfView` default camera and set its `FoV` to approximately 10 degrees.

Then inside `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` instance method use `isNode(:insideFrustumOf:)` method.

Here's working code:

```
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,
                      ARSCNViewDelegate,
                      SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    let sphereNode = SCNNode()
    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    
    public func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
                  updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.sceneView.isNode(self.sphereNode,
                                     insideFrustumOf: self.cameraNode) {
                self.label.text = "In the center..."
            } else {
                self.label.text = "Out OF CENTER"
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.camera?.fieldOfView = 10
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.sceneView.pointOfView!.addChildNode(self.cameraNode)
        }
        
        sphereNode.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.05)
        sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        sphereNode.position.z = -1.0
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

Also, in this solution you may turn on an `orthographic projection` for child camera, instead of `perspective` one. It helps when a model is far from the camera.

```
cameraNode.camera?.usesOrthographicProjection = true
```

Here's how your screen might look like:

[image]

### Next steps

The same way you can append two additional SCNCameras, place them above and below central SCNCamera, and test your object with two extra `isNode(:insideFrustumOf:)` instance methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for valueable answer !, I want to ask you : why did you add camera node to root node, if it's alreay in point of view?

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right., @lady. There's no need to connect this cam to scene's root node. It's just a habit))

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that's not a hack you can use the [`projectPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) API.
It's probably better to work with pixel coordinates because this method uses the actual camera's settings to determine where the object appears on screen.

```
let projectedPoint = sceneView.projectPoint(self.sphereNode.worldPosition)
let xOffset = projectedPoint.x - screenCenter.x; 
let yOffset = projectedPoint.y - screenCenter.y; 
if xOffset * xOffset + yOffset * yOffset < R_squared {
    // inside a disc of radius 'R' at the center of the screen
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by R_squared?

Answer (score 0):

```
    func nodeInCenter() -> SCNNode? {
        let x = (Int(sceneView.projectPoint(sceneView.pointOfView!.worldPosition).x - sceneView.projectPoint(sphereNode.worldPosition).x) ^^ 2) < 9
        let y = (Int(sceneView.projectPoint(sceneView.pointOfView!.worldPosition).y - sceneView.projectPoint(sphereNode.worldPosition).y) ^^ 2) < 9
            if x && y {
                return node
            }
            return nil
        }
```